# propagate hierarchical values from a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have table with structure like this, which represents status changes.

```
+-----------+----------+----------------+-----------------+-------+
| record_id | group_id | attribute type |  change date    | value |
+-----------+----------+----------------+-----------------+-------+
|         1 |        1 | status         | 4/16/2008 18:59 | s1    |
|         2 |        1 | details        | 4/16/2008 18:59 | d5    |
|         3 |        1 | details        | 8/7/2008 18:31  | d2    |
|         4 |        1 | details        | 2/5/2009 22:15  | d1    |
|         5 |        1 | status         | 4/3/2009 21:27  | s2    |
|         6 |        1 | details        | 4/3/2009 21:27  | d7    |
|         7 |        2 | status         | 4/3/2009 21:46  | s1    |
|         8 |        2 | details        | 4/3/2009 21:46  | d1    |
+-----------+----------+----------------+-----------------+-------+
```

I'd like to query status changes and status details changes in two columns, grouped by time stamp (actually any status change makes change to details, so only details change timestamp could be used for easier grouping) and status propagated to related details, like this:

```
+-----------+-----------------+--------+---------+
| object id |  change date    | status | details |
+-----------+-----------------+--------+---------+
|         1 | 4/16/2008 18:59 | s1     | d5      |
|         1 | 8/7/2008 18:31  | s1     | d2      |
|         1 | 2/5/2009 22:15  | s1     | d1      |
|         1 | 4/3/2009 21:27  | s2     | d3      |
|         2 | 4/3/2009 21:46  | s1     | d1      |
+-----------+-----------------+--------+---------+
```

this is what I've started with, but it leaves me with NULLs

```
        SELECT history.record_id,
                history.group_id,
                history.changedate,
                status_chages.value AS status,
                history.value AS details
        FROM history
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT
             history.group_id,
             history.changedate,
             history.value
             FROM history
             WHERE history.attribute_type = 'status') status_chages
        ON status_chages.group_id = history.group_id AND
           status_chages.changedate = history.changedate
        WHERE history.attribute = 'details'
```

First thing which came to my mind is to fill NULLs with previous row data.

But is there a better approach for querying the result listed above?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: For now I'm trying to do this with Postgres, but the target DBMS probably would be MS SQL Sever (added tags)

Comment: Why develop with Postgres when you plan to use SQL Server in production? Those two DBMS are really very different

Comment: I don't have any working instances of SQL Server nearby, and the moving to target DBMS is planned for a not near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query gives desired layout:

```
select 
    group_id, 
    change_date, 
    max(case attr_type when 'status' then value else null end) as status,
    max(case attr_type when 'status' then null else value end) as detail
from history
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;

 group_id |     change_date     | status | detail 
----------+---------------------+--------+--------
        1 | 2008-04-16 18:59:00 | s1     | d5
        1 | 2008-08-07 18:31:00 |        | d2
        1 | 2009-02-05 22:15:00 |        | d1
        1 | 2009-04-03 21:27:00 | s2     | d7
        2 | 2009-04-03 21:46:00 | s1     | d1
(5 rows)
```

You can fill nulls with previous values in such a way:

```
select
    group_id, 
    change_date, 
    max(status) over (partition by group_id, part) status,
    detail
from (
    select *, count(status) over (partition by group_id order by change_date) part
    from (
        select 
            group_id, 
            change_date, 
            max(case attr_type when 'status' then value else null end) as status,
            max(case attr_type when 'status' then null else value end) as detail
        from history
        group by 1, 2
        ) s
    ) s
order by 1, 2;

 group_id |     change_date     | status | detail 
----------+---------------------+--------+--------
        1 | 2008-04-16 18:59:00 | s1     | d5
        1 | 2008-08-07 18:31:00 | s1     | d2
        1 | 2009-02-05 22:15:00 | s1     | d1
        1 | 2009-04-03 21:27:00 | s2     | d7
        2 | 2009-04-03 21:46:00 | s1     | d1
(5 rows)
```

[Test it in rextester.](http://rextester.com/XAW57886)

Comment: Works for me, thanks! And performs better (at least in my environment) than JOIN based query as a first step.